# How to test a function that returns an array of objects whose elements contain javascript Date objects?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, chai

```
obj= {
  "element-id": 0,
  "measurement": [{
    "from": "2018-10-17T13:40:00Z",
    "to": "2018-10-17T13:45:00Z",
    "value": [{
      "value": 9,
      "label": "fw"
    }, {
      "value": 7,
      "label": "bw"
    }]
  }, {
    "from": "2018-10-17T13:45:00Z",
    "to": "2018-10-17T13:50:00Z",
    "value": [{
      "value": 6,
      "label": "fw"
    }, {
      "value": 8,
      "label": "bw"
    }]
  }]
};

var res = foo(obj);

-- Expected res output:
[ { address: 0,
    datetime: 2018-10-17T13:45:00.000Z, <- this is a javascript Date object
    day: '2018-10-17',
    In: 9,
    Out: 7 },
  { address: 0,
    datetime: 2018-10-17T13:50:00.000Z, <- this is a javascript Date object
    day: '2018-10-17',
    In: 6,
    Out: 8 }]
```

Function `foo` should transform object `obj` into another object. The resulting `res` object should be an array whose elements are all structured the same way, and all of them should contain a `Date` object. How can I test this?

Comment: How do you want to achieve day and datetime? What is the logic behind to get `day: '2018-10-17',`?

Comment: day is a string and it is a "temporary" property that will be used in the next step to group all the elements that are associated to the same day. It will be removed in the next step. Datetime is the actual datetime of the record.

Comment: Check the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood from your post and comment. Navigate me through it if there are any mistakes.

```js
obj= {
  "element-id": 0,
  "measurement": [{
    "from": "2018-10-17T13:40:00Z",
    "to": "2018-10-17T13:45:00Z",
    "value": [{
      "value": 9,
      "label": "fw"
    }, {
      "value": 7,
      "label": "bw"
    }]
  }, {
    "from": "2018-10-17T13:45:00Z",
    "to": "2018-10-17T13:50:00Z",
    "value": [{
      "value": 6,
      "label": "fw"
    }, {
      "value": 8,
      "label": "bw"
    }]
  }]
};

let arr = [obj]
let foo = []
arr[0].measurement.map(data => {
 let d = new Date()
 foo.push({
  address: 0,
  datetime: d.toISOString(),
  day: d.toISOString().slice(0,10),
  in: data.value.filter(v => v.label == "fw")[0].value,
  out: data.value.filter(v => v.label == "bw")[0].value
  
 })
})
console.log(foo)
```